# Remove multiple entries for a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I need two columns A and B but of them A has repeated values and B has single unique values. I have to fetch only those values of A which has max(C) value. C is another column.

Comment: Can you please share sample data & desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Row_Number` Analytic function to do this

```
select A,B 
from
(
select row_number() over(partition by A order by C desc)rn,A,B,C
from yourtable
)
where RN=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

> **ROW_NUMBER**
>
> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result
>   set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.
>
> ---
>
> **PARTITION BY value_expression**
>
> Divides the result set produced by the
>   FROM clause into partitions to which the ROW_NUMBER function is
>   applied. value_expression specifies the column by which the result set
>   is partitioned. If PARTITION BY is not specified, the function treats
>   all rows of the query result set as a single group.
>
> ---
>
> **ORDER BY**
>
> The ORDER BY clause determines the sequence in which the rows are assigned their unique ROW_NUMBER within a specified
>   partition. It is required.

---

Sample of `ROW_NUMBER` in your case:

```
SELECT A, B 
FROM
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C DESC) AS RowNum, A, B, C
   FROM   TableName
)
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @NoDisplayName's solution is to use keep dense_rank first/last:

```
with your_table as (select 1 a, 3 b, 10 c from dual union all
                    select 1 a, 2 b, 20 c from dual union all
                    select 1 a, 1 b, 30 c from dual union all
                    select 2 a, 4 b, 40 c from dual union all
                    select 2 a, 5 b, 60 c from dual union all
                    select 2 a, 3 b, 60 c from dual union all
                    select 3 a, 6 b, 70 c from dual union all
                    select 4 a, 2 b, 80 c from dual)
select a,
       max(b) keep (dense_rank first order by c desc) b,
       max(c) max_c
from   your_table
group by a;

         A          B      MAX_C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         30
         2          5         60
         3          6         70
         4          2         80
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `INTERSECT` keyword get those rows which have maximum value of ColC for the ColA.

```
select ColA, ColB from

(
 select ColA, ColB, max(colC) from Tabl 
 group by ColA, ColB

 intersect

 select ColA, ColB, ColC from Tabl
) as A
```